# Write an Elevator Pitch / Tagline

Tags: discussion, top-7, elevator-pitch

### The Elevator Pitch

This isn't as easy as it sounds. Imagine the user who will never read your FAQ and you have two seconds to grab their attention. It should be catchy but descriptive. It should be thoroughly clear but painfully concise. **Make every... word... count.**

Here are some creative examples:

- [Gawker](http://gawker.com/): Daily Manhattan media news and gossip. Reporting live from the center of the universe.
- [Gizmodo](http://gizmodo.com/): The gadget guide. So much in love with shiny new toys, it’s unnatural.
- [Autoblog](http://www.autoblog.com/): We obsessively cover the auto industry.
- [DumbLittleMan](http://www.dumblittleman.com/): So what do we do here? Well, it’s simple. 15 to 20 times per week we provide tips that will save you money, increase your productivity, or simply keep you sane.
- [Needcoffee.com](http://www.needcoffee.com/): We are the Internet equivalent of a triple espresso with whipped cream. Mmmm…whipped cream.

### Use it as a Tagline

A shorter elevator pitch *can* be used as a tagline — something you can display in the header at the top of the page. If it doesn't fit, consider shortening it or creating a separate tagline. Here are some great examples:

- [Slashdot](http://slashdot.org/): News for nerds. Stuff that matters.
- [Lifehacker](http://www.lifehacker.com/): Don’t live to geek, geek to live!
- [The Simple Dollar](http://www.thesimpledollar.com/): Financial talk for the rest of us.

### The Motto (don't forget your logo)

A logo begs for it own little, short tagline — like a motto. Maybe the tagline inspires the logo; Maybe it's the other way around. Mottos make good t-shirt, bumper stickers, and other marketing material. Either way, you'll recognize a good motto when you see it:

- Just do it.
- Think Different.
- The Uncola.
- Intel inside.
- Like a rock.
- The king of beers.

…and perhaps all this leads to a proper name and domain for your site… *eventually*. So let's start from the basics. **Come up with a killer elevator pitch, tagline, and/or motto!**

Comment: I am assuming one "pitch" per answer for voting purposes? Is this still an active question?

Answer (score 3):

Yeah, it's probably corny, but I figured this would get the ball rolling.

**The Tag Line**

> Card and Board Games:  We love games more than anyone else.

**The Motto**

> That's how we roll.

I'm aware the phrase "We love games more than anyone else" may irritate other board-game discussion sites, but to me it certainly gets your attention, and could get people talking.

Answer (score 2):

We know everything about games so you don't have to.

Variations:

- We know everything so you don't have to
- We know what you don't
- We know everything about gaming so you don't need to
- Knowing everything about games
- We know
- We know all games

Answer (score 1):

**The Tag Line**: You may not know Jack, but we do!

Answer (score 1):

**Motto**: Aces who know Jack.

(This is a bit heavy on the Card side, though.)

Answer (score 1):

**Motto:** Board Gaming Q&A done right.

In my opinion, this would tell a user what BG.SE all about, and also convey its key difference to BGG as an all-embracing board gaming website:

BG.SE is specialized on one aspect only (board gaming Q&A), and actively tries to excel there. BGG on the other hand has lots of different features and aspects - it's good on many of them, but one can hardly expect them to excel at *every aspect* of their site.

Comment: very nice!  I like it.

Comment: although judging by the definitions from the question, that's more of a tagline than a motto...

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a bit corny...

> Board and Card Games: Answers from the Kings and Queens of gaming...

Answer (score -1):

**The Motto** (or maybe even name for the site?)

Cardboard Conundrums

**The Tagline** (maybe too long, might be more of an elevator pitch)

Answering questions on games of wits and luck since 2010.

Answer (score -1):

**Motto**:  Board Gaming Demystified